# How to send a form with multiple fields to server and then display it in a different tab on the same site?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, body-parser

Consider the following sample form:

```
<form>
  <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br>
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname">
</form>
```

Consider it is contained within a `tabs` bootstrap structured page, like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
      <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">...</div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">
        <form>
          <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
          <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br>
          <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
          <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname">
<input type="submit" action="/" aria-label="Submit">
        </form>
    </div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">...</div>
    </div>
```

In the example above, the form would be found within the `profile` tab.

How can I send the form fields' inputted data back to the server to be stored, and then displayed in another, different tab, say the `home` tab?

My first attempt was defining an app.js with

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

    var items = [];, 
    
    const item = {fname: String, lname: String}; 
    
    items.push(item);
```

Now, the idea is that when the user clicks the `submit` button, body parser reads the names of the form fields' and sends them into the array, then the array has to be displayed in the other tab. I'm not sure exactly... *how* to structure it, like, I half-understand how it works but I just can't quite make it.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

If your purpose is to just display data from your form to another page of your website without saving it permanently to a database
 You could just store them on localStorage and access the localStorage on the other page and display them.

```
//in your client-side js file get the fields from the dom
const firstName = getElementbyId("fname");
const lastName = getElementbyId("lname");

//when the user submits the form have a function that makes and object with the values of the inputs

const onSubmit = () =>{
    const userObj = {
      fName: firstName.value,
      lName: lastName.value
    }
    
    //then store the object as a string (with JSON.stringify) to your localStorage
    //localStorage only stores strings

    localStorage.setItem("userData", JSON.stringify(userObj))
}

//and make another function to run onLoad on the page you want to display it

const displayFunction = () =>{

   const userData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userData")) //you parse it back into an object with JSON.parse because it was stored as a string
   
   //you can do stuff with the data here as well like append it to an element
   //or you could store the data in a global variable to use it later.
 }

//just put the function on the tag of the home page
//say you want it when the body loads

<body onload="displayFunction()">
```

If you want that data to persist even when the user uses another device you can store it to a database.
mongoose works well with node-js and you can use mongodb atlas as your database for free.

- make a User Schema
- make an upload route
- then make an http request from your client-side and send the form inputs to your server and process them there and store them to the DB